# Как получить Drawable или Bitmap из Vector Drawable не из ресурсов?

Tags: android, android-drawable, vector-drawable

Всем привет. Имеется приложение с сеткой векторных иконок. Будет функция копирования иконки в память. Итог: необходимо показывать иконки и в то же время возможность их копирования в память устройства. Если разместить xml ресурсы векторных иконок в папкe `res/drawable` то он скомпилируется в ресурс и его невозможно будет никуда копировать. Если же разместить иконки в assets, то их можно будет копировать в память устройства, но невозможно будет показать в `ImageView`. Как решить эту проблему кроме как размещая иконки и в drawable и в assets?

Comment: Так что Вы хотите сохранять: картинку или исходный xml-файл, и собственно для чего?

Comment: @woesss, выводить на экран пользователя иконку чтобы было видно что выбрать. А сохранять в память ее исходный xml код. Я просто пишу приложение для быстрого добавления нужной иконки в проект мобильной IDE

Answer (score 0):

Может вот так ?

```
Drawable.createFromResourceStream(resources,new TypedValue(), resources.getAssets().open(filename), null)
```

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/246554)

Comment: Автору нужно получить drawable из assets. Я привел строчку кода которая возвращает drawable из assets. Куда уж точнее. И что уточнить ?

Comment: Перечитайте последнее предложение автора. "Как решить эту проблему кроме как размещая иконки и в drawable и в assets?" Вы все еще считаете что ответили на вопрос?